# Stopping times on Markov chains: what is this symbol $X_\tau$? Am I blind?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I'm reading about Markov chain and stopping times from Varadhan's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821828525) on Probabality (See also his [notes](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Evaradhan/course/PROB.ch4.pdf) on his website).

Roughly speaking, the data for Markov Chain is a state space with a $\sigma$-algebra $(\mathcal X,\mathcal{F})$, an initial probability $\mu_0$ on $\mathcal X$, and transition probabilities $\{\pi_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ on $\mathcal X$ which depend measurably on previous states.
From this one can construct a space of Markov chains with a probability $(\Omega:=\mathcal X^{\{0\}\cup \mathbb{N}},\mathcal{F}^\infty:=\mathcal{F}^{\{0\}\cup \mathbb{N}}, P)$.
Denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the projections to the $0,\dots,n$ coordinates by $\mathcal{F}_n$.

A $\textit{Stopping time}$ $\tau :\Omega \to \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$ is a function for which
$$
\tau^{-1}\{n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n \text{ for all } n\geq 0.
$$

**Question:** On the bottom of page 89 of the book (or page 22 of the notes) author defines the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ and claims that $X_\tau$ is measurable with respect to this algebra. What is the symbol $X_\tau$? He hasn't defined it before. Am I blind?

I also look at the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461447070) of Gut and there's the same symbol on page 495 without a definition.

Comment: Informally, $X_\tau$ is the value from $\mathcal X$ when you stop

Comment: $\tau$ can be considered a random time, thus $X_\tau$ is a random variable, which is a stochastic process $\mathcal{X}$ evaluated at some random time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we write $X_\tau$, we are indexing into the sequence $X_0, X_1, X_2, \dots$ (of random variables: the states of the Markov chain at time $0, 1, 2, \dots$) by the random variable $\tau$.

Very formally (more formally than anyone writes) $X_\tau$ is the random variable whose value at an outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ is $X_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)$.

Comment: Thank you for the formal definition sir, will accept once it allows me.